# javascript apply() function, jQuery and the 'this' pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, apply

I'm trying to understand what is going on in this code, please correct me if I'm mistaken

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function () {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    var later = function () {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
}

$(document).on("keyup", "#SearchTerm", debounce(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(e.target).closest('form');
  $(form).submit();
}, 300))
```

Firstly the returned function from debounce, this executes immediately and the *this* reference / context will be the "#SearchTerm" input element because jQuery attached the function call on its keyup event?

Secondly, in this instance is the arguments object automatically populated by the jQuery 'keyup' event?

Thanks!

Comment: It will better if you debug the code step by step in browser console as it will clear all your doubts.

Comment: I have been doing this, I just wanted to check my interpretation was correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Firstly the returned function from debounce, this executes immediately and the this reference / context will be the "#SearchTerm" input element because jQuery attached the function call on its keyup event?

This is correct.

> Secondly, in this instance is the arguments object automatically populated by the jQuery 'keyup' event?

`arguments` is a native JS construct which doesn't have anything to do with jQuery. It returns an array-like object which contains all the parameters passed to the function. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I've read that link and know that it is a native JS construct. I am assuming the jQuery event handler passes this extra information to the debounce function and when executed (in the context of #SearchTerm keyup) uses the arguments object to fulfil passed in func's 'e' parameter? so we can do e.preventDefault() etc

Comment: That's right - jQuery passes the handler function the `event` which was raised, along with any additional information that was programmatically sent. In your case you don't need to worry about that though. See the API docs for [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more detail about it

Comment: Thanks Rory, I have an annoying habit of trying to understand everything!

Comment: Nothing annoying about that :)